# Cooling of a solid vs hollow sphere

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

We have a solid and a hollow sphere made of same material, and of same dimensions.
We have to compare the temperatures of the sphere after a long time of cooling.

So initially I can safely say that cooling by radiation will take place or:
$$H=\epsilon A\sigma (\Delta T^4)$$

So initial rate of cooling will be same. However after inital conditions, the condcution will aslo take place inside the solid sphere, and here i start to have difficulty writing the equation for heat loss.

For the conduction, we have: $$H=\frac{KAdT}{dx}$$
Solving for a solid sphere case I get:
$$H=KA\Delta T\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}\right)$$

So we have conduction which is bringing in heat from beneath and heat leaving from the surface by radiation, so, how can I write net equation for the heat loss by the sphere and compare it quantitatively with hollow sphere?
Answer is that solid sphere would stay warmer than the hollow one.

Comment: At the initial moment in time, the radiative energy loss is the same. That does not imply that the _cooling_ is the same.

Comment: If I remember right there is no analytic solution for the spherical heat diffusion equation in a solid sphere when the boundary condition is radiative. I get the feeling this problem requires a numerical solution. Unless it is just a trick question: a hollow sphere of the same radius as a filled sphere will have much less thermal capacity and stored heat, so it will cool down much faster.

Comment: @Ghoster Sorry I meant the sphere

Answer (score 0):

(Note that I don't promise a rigorous proof, but this exposition may provide ideas.)

For both spheres, the [conductive heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) applies with [axisymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula):

$$\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{\alpha}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial r}\right)=\alpha\left(\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2T(r,t)}{\partial^2 r}\right),$$

with thermal diffusivity $\alpha$. The initial and boundary conditions are

$$T(r,0)=T_0;$$

$$\frac{dT(r_\text{inner},t)}{dr}=0;$$

$$-k\frac{dT(r_\text{outer},t)}{dr}=\epsilon\sigma[T(r_\text{outer},t)^4-T_\infty^4],$$

with thermal conductivity $k$, inner radius $r_\text{inner}$ (equal to 0 for the solid sphere), outer radius $r_\text{outer}$, emissivity $\epsilon$, Stefan–Boltzmann constant $\sigma$, and enclosure temperature $T_\infty$.

(The boundary conditions come from realizing that no outward heat flux can exist from the center/interior surface and from setting the conductive heat flux just inside the outer surface equal to the radiative transfer away from that surface.)

My aim is to avoid a numerical solution but rather to consider scaling arguments, for example, to obtain qualitative results that might build intuition. So consider the finite-difference version of the heat equation above:

$$\frac{\Delta T_t}{\Delta t}=\alpha\left[\frac{2}{r}\frac{\Delta T_r}{\Delta r}+\left(\frac{\Delta T_r}{\Delta r}\right)^2\right],$$

where $r=r_\text{outer}$ and $\Delta r=r_\text{outer}-r_\text{inner}$ and where $\Delta T_t$ and $\Delta T_r$ refer to temporal and spatial differences, respectively.

Consider the first moments of cooling at $r=r_\text{inner}$ (the center and inner surface of the solid and hollow sphere, respectively). The surface temperature $T(r_\text{outer},t)$ must be the same for both spheres, as the diffusive conduction process hasn't had time to "know" that the center is hollow or not. Thus, $\Delta T_r$ is constant, as are $\alpha$ and $r=r_\text{outer}$, and $\Delta r$ is smaller for the hollow sphere, so $\frac{\Delta T_t}{\Delta t}$ must be larger for the hollow sphere, corresponding to more rapid cooling. In a hand-wavy way, I'll conclude that the hollow sphere—which contains less mass and no heat source—must subsequently remain cooler as the two spheres asymptotically approach $T_\infty$.

Comment: Note how this answer focuses on temperature rather than heat.  This is because an object does not have heat.  It does have temperature, which can be translated into kinetic energy stored within the random vibrations of the molecules of the material.  Heat transfer is the rate (Joules per second) of transfer of the energy that is proportional to temperature.